# Can my job see what I do on my home computer if I use my work computer on my home network?

Tags: vpn, surveillance

I'm currently using a work computer on my home network. On the work computer, I'm connected to the company's VPN. Can my work see what I'm doing on my home computer because it's connected to my home wifi, just like my work laptop?

Answer (score 5):

This is a new permutation of this question.

No, any monitoring software on your **work** computer cannot see what is going on with your **personal** computers.

No, the company network monitoring technology cannot see what is going on in your personal computers if your personal computers are not using the company VPN.

Concerns like this should be asked of your IT department because inadvertent monitoring of non-work devices would be a big problem in most countries.